# How to merge two DOCX in PHP?

Tags: php, merge, docx

how can I merge two docx with PHP without loosing images or something else. 
doc1.docx should be only pasted at the end of doc2.docx

I have tried it with TbsZip but there are missing all pictures of doc1.docx:

```
include_once('tbszip.php');

$zip = new clsTbsZip();

// Open the first document
$zip->Open('doc1.docx');
$content1 = $zip->FileRead('word/document.xml');
$zip->Close();

// Extract the content of the first document
$p = strpos($content1, '<w:body');
if ($p===false) exit("Tag <w:body> not found in document 1.");
$p = strpos($content1, '>', $p);
$content1 = substr($content1, $p+1);
$p = strpos($content1, '</w:body>');
if ($p===false) exit("Tag </w:body> not found in document 1.");
$content1 = substr($content1, 0, $p);

// Insert into the second document
$zip->Open('doc2.docx');
$content2 = $zip->FileRead('word/document.xml');
$p = strpos($content2, '</w:body>');
if ($p===false) exit("Tag </w:body> not found in document 2.");
$content2 = substr_replace($content2, $content1, $p, 0);
$zip->FileReplace('word/document.xml', $content2, TBSZIP_STRING);

// Save the merge into a third file
$zip->Flush(TBSZIP_FILE, 'merge.docx');
```

Comment: And what is the problem with this code

Comment: @RiggsFolly The pictures of doc1 are missing.

Comment: If you unzip a `.docx` you will see all the files that make up a `docx`. You didnt copy over the images from the source to the new `merge.docx`

Comment: @RiggsFolly How can I do it?

Comment: I dont know! However you have a set of folders in a `docx` zip file. If you want to make a new one from 2 others, you have to work out how to build a valid data structure to match what Word will expect when you attempt to look at the new file using Word